# Docker Error Pulling Images in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I'm trying to pull image in docker and it gives following error:

> root@ubuntu:~# docker pull hello-world
>
> Pulling repository hello-world
>
> FATA[0003] Get
>   https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/hello-world/images:
>   x509: failed to load system roots and no roots provided

Answer (score 0):

make sure your system time is set correctly. I saw this error, when my VM time was not in sync with the real world.

try

```
sudo ntpdate time.nist.gov
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update repos, remove lxc-docker and install docker-engine

1. add the new gpg key

   ```
   $ apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D
   ```
2. edit your /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list

   ```
   $ vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list

   #remove the contents and replace with the following depending on your os  and version:
   ```

   ## Debian Wheezy

   ```
   deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo debian-wheezy main
   ```

   ## Debian Jessie

   ```
   deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo debian-jessie main
   ```

   ## Debian Stretch/Sid

   ```
   deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo debian-stretch main
   ```

   ## Ubuntu Precise

   ```
   deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-precise main
   ```

   ## Ubuntu Trusty

   ```
   deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-trusty main
   ```

   ## Ubuntu Utopic

   ```
   deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-utopic main
   ```

   ## Ubuntu Vivid

   ```
   deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-vivid main
   ```

   ## Ubuntu Wily

   ```
   deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-wily main
   ```
3. After your source file is updated run the following:

   ```
   $ apt-get update
   ```
4. remove the old

   ```
   $ apt-get purge lxc-docker*
   ```
5. install the new

   ```
   $ apt-get install docker-engine
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem is by running two command
this are `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates ca-certificates-java`

```
sudo service docker restart
```

now pull any thig

Answer (score 0):

Two way to fix.

1) you can login into docker: docker login (console command) - 10% can help

2) docker have problem with installation on ubuntu.

You need to edit file /etc/resolv.conf

2.1) add to this file next two lines

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

`nameserver 8.8.4.4`

2.2) and restart docker

```
sudo service docker restart
```